# Moving an existing WP site from an addon domain to subfolder of primary domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

In a cPanel shared account, I have some addon domains that are installed in their own subfolders as usual and a primary domain installed at root.

This primary domain (that currently hosts a static HTML - non WordPress - site) is being dropped so I'll have to change the primary and switch to one of the addon domains.

How should I edit its `.htaccess` file to point correctly to the subfolder when it will become a primary domain?

Current `.htaccess` in the `/subfolder` is the usual:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Not yet tried because the primary domain has not yet been changed.

Answer (score 2):

To update the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file it's perhaps preferable to update the "WordPress Address (URL)" (`WP_HOME`) and "Site Address (URL)" (`WP_SITEURL`) options in "General Settings" in the WordPress dashboard. (Or set the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants directly in `wp-config.php`.) For example:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/subfolder');    // WordPress Address
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');           // Site Address
```

Where `WP_SITEURL` is the base URL that user's see in the browser address bar and `WP_HOME` is the location of the WordPress core files, where WP is actually installed.

This should then update the `/subfolder/.htaccess` accordingly:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

*Aside:* However, if you are manually coding your `.htaccess` file, you would use the following instead, since there is no *need* to explicitly reference `/subfolder` in this file (or use `RewriteBase`). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

---

You then need to change the root `.htaccess` file to simply direct all requests to the `/subfolder`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Note the absence of the slash prefix on the *substitution* string.

(The presence of the site's `.htaccess` file in the `/subfolder` prevents a rewrite-loop since mod-rewrite is not inherited by default.)

So now, when a request comes in for `/foo` the root `.htaccess` file internally rewrites the request to `/subfolder/foo` and the `/subfolder/.htaccess` takes over and routes the request through WordPress (in the subfolder).

Comment: Many thanks, but just to be sure I understand correctly:
The snippet I posted above is the current one residing at subfolder.

The current root htaccess is almost empty and only includes references for the PHP version as there is no WP install for the moment there (the current primary is a simple HTML site).

So, if I understand correctly is to add just those 2 lines in this htaccess (RewriteEngine & RewriteRule) - correct? Your last paragraph makes me think that I got it right but just to be sure + thanks again!

Comment: @dsl225 Ah OK, I thought that was the one in the root. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Sorry my initial answer was posted incomplete, sorry about that. Now it is here in full.

Comment: @dsl225 Is that the actual file contents? Have you removed the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment markers and maintain the code yourself (preventing WP from overwriting it)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion! I posted only the most relevant lines of the snippet for clarity here but that was a bad idea... Just edited my initial post to include the full WP snippet.

Comment: @dsl225 I've updated/rewritten my answer.

Comment: thanks for the update!  I would prefer avoid using the first option inside WP and prefer your initial approach. Just to clarify, if using this one (Aside section) I understand I have to leave the existing WP .htaccess untouched - right? Or did you remove the line with "RewriteBase /"? 
And then just create a new .htaccess at root with those 2 lines - right?

Comment: @dsl225 "I would prefer avoid using the first option inside WP and prefer your initial approach." - You do need to change the WordPress settings (inside WordPress) in order to update the `.htaccess` file and possibly for other internal WordPress schenanigans. "if using this one (Aside section) I understand I have to leave the existing WP .htaccess untouched - right?" - No, that would replace the existing WordPress `.htaccess` file. (But you would then need to lock-down `.htaccess` to prevent WP overwriting it, which is good for security but possibly makes maintenance harder.)

Comment: @dsl225 "Or did you remove the line with "RewriteBase /"?" - Yes, I removed that (and the `<IfModule>` wrapper). IF you are hand coding this (and not using WordPress or letting WordPress maintain the `.htaccess` file) then that is how you would write it (simpler). (I don't know why WordPress does it the way it does.) "And then just create a new .htaccess at root with those 2 lines - right?" - Yes.

Comment: Confirming that your solution works and I bring some additional remarks:
/// I used the first option: first added the 2 lines in the new htaccess at root folder, then logged in successfully and modified both URLs in Dashboard under General Settings.
/// Everything seems to work fine but the old htaccess file that is now under the subfolder was NOT modified by WP.
/// In this site, I have mainly 2 plugins that write large blocks in the htaccess file: iThemes Security and WP Fastest Cache. Both of them keep them inside the subfolder/htcaccess + they added the same at root!

Comment: I also wanted to note here that, in the meanwhile, I found this WP page here:
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/
/// I tested their first option and didn't work and gave up because I find their explanations confusing. I don't understand the meaning "URL change" they use there because we have 2 URLS and they don't specify which one /// The second one looks similar to yours but not exactly the same.